# How can I download reliable history database in metatrader 4?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, forex, mt4

My history data base has been deleted and I download it from some sites,
The new data give me different answers than before!
How can I get history data from 2020 onwards from mt4?

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way to get historical data is to save it on a daily/weekly basis from the broker you are trading with. Ideally you want all the M1 data (you can build any of the other timeframes using M1 data and this is the best and most consistent way of backtesting with MetaTrader 4).

There are other options, downloading using the terminal from the history centre, purchasing data from third party web sites, however these will all be slightly different from your own brokers (with many having gaps in the data).

Comment: THANKS, but I want 2020 onward and mt4 history centers  only has 3 months data for M1.